# Des paroles de Laplace que je ne comprends pas

Tags: mathématiques

J’ai besoin de votre conseil pour comprendre les propos du mathématicien *Pierre Simon Laplace* quand il enseigne des élèves à *l’École Centrale Supérieure*. Si vous suivez [ce lien](http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/rhs_0151-4105_1980_num_33_4_1727) et vous ouvrez le fichier vers lequel il vous redirige à page numéro 344, vous trouvez les propos dont il s’agit.

Il semble dire qu’une série converge lorsque

> les termes qui suivent ceux que l’on considère soient très petits et
>   d’autant moindres que l’on prend un plus grand nombre de termes dans
>   la série

Je dirais que par *les termes que l’on considère* il entend les *N* premiers termes, ou *N* est un grand entier quelconque. Alors, *les termes qui les suivent* sont **tous** les autres termes, donc il y en a infiniment beaucoup. Il me paraît donc qu’ils doivent être petits par rapport à au aux *N* termes au début.

J’ai peur de ne pas avoir compris comment le morceau « d’autant moindres que » s’insère dans cette phrase. Sans tenir compte de la phrase, je dirais qu’il peut être pris dans les sens suivants : *Tant plus petits que (quelque chose)*, et *tellement petit que (quelque chose se passe)*. Je crois que le deuxième sens va mieux dans cette phrase : Si je prends le morceau dans ce sens, la phrase parait bonne, grammaticalement.

Toutefois, la fin de la phrase, « l’on prend un plus grand nombre de termes dans la série » n’a pas l’air de tenir debout devant ce dernier constat. Je m’attendais plutôt à ce que Laplace dirait :

> les termes qui suivent ceux que l’on considère soient très petits et
>   d’autant moindres que l’on peut les négliger

J’espère que vous comprenez qu’est-ce qui m’embête, que vous voyez qu’est-ce que cette phrase veut dire, et que vous pouvez me l’expliquer.

---

Malheureusement, le fichier dans lequel j’ai lu les paroles de Laplace ne donne qu’un morceau de sa phrase. Le début manque, mais avec ce que l’on a y a ajouté, ça devrait paraître sensé quand même. Si on suit le lien que j’ai inclus, on rencontre ce que montre l’instantané que j’ai pris de mon écran pour éviter des fautes de frappe.

### [image: Un instantané du fichier]

Ceci sert à faire suite au ce que *Ampiteóth* m’a dit. Je dois vous remercier pour votre conseil, mais il faut aussi que je vous dise qu’il ne me parait pas sage de lire tous les travaux de Laplace, puisque la phrase dont il s’agit est tirée d’un discours que Lagrange avait une fois tenu.  Il parait que le morceau était assez pour faire comprendre aux français qu’est-ce que Laplace pensait de la notion de convergence. C’est pourquoi je fais recours à cette communauté maintenant. Je vous prie donc de me dire à quoi le bout de l’extrait se rapporte, sauf s’il n’y a aucune façon d’en dire quelque chose de sensé sans tenir compte de la fin de la phrase.

Comment: Quel est le début de la phrase ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, j'ai ajouté quelque chose à ce que j'ai écrit pour répondre à votre commentaire. J'espère que cela vous aide à comprendre ce que Laplace dit.

Comment: Voir notes 6 et 33. L'extrait présenté par [Jean Dhormes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Dhombres) est tronqué et il faut donc vérifier dans les [_Oeuvres complètes_](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?adva=1&adv=1&tri=&t_relation=%22cb30739022p%22&lang=en) de M. Laplace. Il n'y a même pas de point à l'intérieur du guillemet final alors on ne sait pas si c'est la fin de la phrase. Enfin il s'agit d'une réponse à une prétention quant à la non-universalité d'une règle présentée(si je comprends). Le document fait état du manque de rigueur p/r aux fondements à l'époque etc. On est loin du "traité".

Comment: @Amphiteóth, Merci beaucoup pour m’avoir répondu. Si vous voulez, vous pouvez lire ce que je pense de votre commentaire et m’aider davantage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> de toutes les expressions ou séries, il faut avoir soin qu'elles soient convergentes, c'est à dire que les termes qui suivent ceux que l’on considère soient très petits et d’autant moindres que l’on prend un plus grand nombre de termes dans la série

En mathématiques modernes, il considère une série dont le terme général est par exemple x_n. Les premiers x_n (ceux pour n < N par exemple) sont "ceux que l'on considère". Les termes qui suivent sont alors les x_n avec n >= N. Pour que la série converge, il faut que ces termes, ceux qui suivent, soient très petits.

> d’autant moindres que l’on prend un plus grand nombre de termes dans la série

"Plus grand nombre de termes" se réfère à N : plus on prend de x_n, et plus les termes "qui suivent" sont "d'autant moindres". En d'autres termes, la somme des termes pour n > N tend vers zéro quand N tend vers l'infini. C'est ce qui est expliqué dans la suite du document par Laplace. Il écrit :

> en sorte que ce qui est négligé, devienne de plus en plus insensible et moindre qu'aucune grandeur donnée.

"Ce qui est négligé" est la somme des termes qui suivent, et Laplace demande qu'elle devienne de plus en plus petite (et même plus petite que n'importe quelle grandeur donnée) quand on prend un nombre de termes (N) plus grand. C'est essentiellement la définition epsilon-delta moderne des limites.

Comment: @Amphiteóth C'est sur la page suivante dans le texte cité dans la question...

Comment: Merci pour l'éclaircissement! Pourriez-vous me dire quelle est au juste la fonction que le mot "que" remplit dans le morceau "que l'on prend"?

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Je ne suis pas linguiste, mais je pense qu'il introduit une proposition subordonnée circonstancielle. En français moderne on écrirait, je pense, "que les termes qui suivent [...] soient très petits et d'autant moindres *lorsque* l'on prend un plus grand nombre de termes dans la série" ou "*quand on* prend un plus grand nombre de termes dans la série".